# Why isn't my class constructor initializing its member variables?

Tags: c++

Forgive me if the information is a bit lacking as I am trying to follow the recommended "Asking Guidelines".

I have created a class called "Item" to store item information and have defined my constructor as follows:

```
Item::Item(std::string number, std::string name, int quantity, double price) {
    itemNumber = number;
    itemName = name;
    quantity = quantity;
    unitPrice = price;
}
```

and I initialize it in my main function like so:

```
Item temp("string", "string", 0, 0);
```

but when I printed the values of item, only itemNumber and itemName printed correctly.all that printed was random garbage.  Then I realized the issue is quantity and price aren't getting initialized.  Why is that?

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should use unique variable names. This is also one of the reasons various style guides suggest a `'m_'` prefix to variables that are member variables, e.g. `m_quantity = quantity`

Comment: Oh wow, that pretty much did it. I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @Cyber I dislike this a lot! I prefer giving class members a `_` postfix. But well, every swan has to die it's very individual way.

Comment: Pass strings as const references - it saves on fuel

Comment: *Why isn't my class constructor initializing its member variables?* beacuse thats not initialization, is assigment. Also be carefull with naming scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
this->quantity = quantity;
```

or (IMHO better):

```
Item::Item(const std::string& number, const std::string& name, int quantity_, double price) {
                                                          // ^
    // ...
    quantity = quantity_;
    // ...
}
```

or (IMHO even better) use a constructor initializer list:

```
Item::Item(const std::string& number, const std::string name&, int quantity, double price) 
: itemNumber(number), itemName(name), quantity(quantity), unitPrice(price) {}
```

> *" Why is that?"*

The parameter name currently shadows your member variable name in the constructor's body scope.

---

Personally I tend to have class declarations like follows

```
class Item {
public:
    Item(const std::string& number, const std::string& name, int quantity, double price) 
    : itemNumber_(number)
    , itemName_(name)
    , quantity_(quantity)
    , unitPrice_(price) {}
private:
    std::string itemNumber_;
    std::string itemName_;
    int quantity_;
    double unitPrice_ 
};
```

Comment: Why add `_` to one parameter and not the other, it's not consistent.

Comment: @NeilKirk Well, the others aren't shadowing any member variable names. Would confuse more, than clarify IMHO.

Comment: Why don't you give the class member the `_` postfix instead of the parameter like you state in the question comment?  I believe that would make it more consistent and less confusing.

Comment: @Kaiged In fact, [that's my preferred pattern for class member declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262967/why-isnt-my-class-constructor-initializing-its-member-variables#comment41201597_26262967). Though I retained focussing on this point, in favor of clarity for the OP.

Comment: @Kaiged Well, though I appreciate your applause, it's completely opinion based to accept this as a _good coding_ style. There might be Coding Conventions that disagree using such.

Comment: If using the ctor initializer list you don't need to worry about shadowing

Comment: @MattMcNabb I've shown being aware of this: `... itemName(name), /*  >> */ quantity(quantity) /*  << */, unitPrice(price) ...`

Answer (score 0):

`quantity = quantity;` Both here refer to the parameter, and not the member variable.
To refer to a member variable inside a function which has a parameter of the same name, you must use the this pointer, eg `this->quantity = quantity;` or alternatively qualify it with the class name eg `Item::quantity = quantity;`

Alternatively use the initialization list to avoid this problem and possibly initialize your class more efficiently.

```
Item::Item(const std::string& number, const std::string& name, int quantity, double price)
: itemNumber(number)
, itemName(name)
, quantity(quantity)
, price(price)
{
}
```

I took the liberty of making your string parameters const reference to avoid a copy.

Comment: but you are making a copy by doing `itemNumber(number), itemName(name)` anyway. You are just shifting the copy to a different place and making it harder for the compiler to optimize.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Maybe in C++11, I'm not sure, but not in old C++. And any micro-optimization involving a string with heap allocations is going to be negligible. Const references never let me down. Const references did me good.